# Can ParamConverterProvider be injected in a POJO?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, cdi

I tried

```
@Context ParamConverterProvider ctxProvider;
```

or

```
@Inject ParamConverterProvider ctxProvider;
```

or

```
@Inject javax.inject.Provider<ParamConverterProvider> ctxProvider;
```

none of those seem to work, `ctxProvider` is `null`. Is it really possible to inject any `@Provider` Annotated Class, or am I missing something?

UPDATE:
In a JAX-RS 2.0 application, I have to implement a function that basically converts String values to specific Data Types:

```
public <E> E convert(Class<E> type, String val)
```

I could of course `switch ... case` for every known `type` but I thought since in a JAX-RS container, I should leverage the built-in `ParamConverter` -s.

I don't want to be dependent of the implementation, thus I was trying to Inject ParamConverterProvider interface, and hopefully the jax runtime would provide the correct implementation of the container.

As @peeskillet pointed out, now I get that there may be more than one ParamConverterProvider.

Is it possible to get access somehow of one ParamConverter, the same way JAX runtime decides what converter to use, based on ranking and data type?

Comment: _Why?_ Sound like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you fully describe your use case (with code examples). Maybe there is a different solution to the main problem.

Comment: I need to implement a feature in a jax-rs 2.0 environment, that basically should convert String values (stored somewhere) in specific Data Types (Integer, Date etc.). In order to be consistent throughout the application, I wanted to take advantage of the already provided ParamConverter-s of the Container.

Comment: 1) Where/when you are trying to inject it makes a difference for how/if to inject. That's why I asked you to _"fully describe your use case (with code examples)"_. 2) There is more than just one provider, so you can't try to inject just one. You either need a specific one, or a list of providers. 3) The injection also depends on the JAX-RS implementation. I don't think standard CDI will help you here. You will need to take advantage of the implementation specific DI. So providing the implementation would help

Comment: If you decide to provide this new information, please update your post with it, rather then posting it the comments.

Comment: ok, thanks :) will do